# Java Constructor with extends keyword

Tags: java, constructor

I have a java Class that looks like this:

```
public class thisThing {

    private final Class<? extends anInterface> member;

    public thisThing(Class<? extends anInterface> member) {
        this.member = member;
    }
}
```

My Question is: How do I call the `thisThing` Constructor?

Comment: I may not be understanding your question, but don't you need to simply call new thisThing() and pass as an argument any object that implements anInterface?

Comment: Learn the Java coding standards: should be ThisThing

Comment: You just pass it a class that implements the interface...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to call the constructor of `thisThing` you need to define a class that implements `anInterface` first:

```
class ClassForThisThing implements anInterface {
    ... // interface methods go here
}
```

Now you can instantiate `thisThing` as follows:

```
thisThing theThing = new thisThing(ClassForThisThing.class);
```

The idea behind such instantiations is usually giving `thisThing` a class from which it could create instances of `anInterface` through reflection. Compiler makes sure that the class that you pass to the constructor is compatible with `anInterface`, ensuring that casts like this

```
anInterface memberInstance = (anInterface)member.newInstance();
```

would always succeed at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

I would not like what you've done.

Why not this?  No need for generics here.  You are just doing composition.  Pass in any reference that implements `AnInterface`.   The Liskov substitution principle says everything will work fine.

```
public class ThisThing {

    private AnInterface member;

    public ThisThing(AnInterface member) {
        this.member = member;
    }
}
```

Here's the interface:

```
public interface AnInterface {
    void doSomething();
}
```

Here's an implementation:

```
public class Demo implements AnInterface {
    public void doSomething() { System.out.println("Did it"); }
}
```

Comment: Defined thisThing ... its supplied as is.

Comment: Bad definition.